Many To Many Relationship - coding conflicts
public class Invoice {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
 
    // Some fields ...
    
 
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "invoice_elements",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "element_id")
    )
    private List<CostElements> costElements;
}

public class CostElements {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
 
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "costElements")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
}

        // InvoiceRequest Dto has both invoice data and cost elements data.              

        @Override
        public void saveInvoice(InvoiceRequest invoiceRequest) {
    
        CostElements costElement1 = new CostElements();
        costElement1.setName(invoiceRequest.getName());
        costElement1.setInvoices();
 
        CostElements costElement2 = new CostElements();
        costElements2.setName(invoiceRequest.getName());
        costElements2.setInvoices();
 
        List<CostElements> elementList = new ArrayList<>();
        elementList.add(costElement1);
        elementList.add(costElement2);
 
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();   
        invoice.setCostElements(elementList);
}

Look at the saveInvoice() method. My question is how should I save costElements and Invoice correctly. How can I handle these setter methods correctly ? -> costElement1.setInvoices(); costElements2.setInvoices(); Because even though there is a setter method called -> setInvoices(); But we have only one Invoice. Can anyone please clarify this problem for me ?

But it is not working as I expected. what is expected?

Some of your annotations are not standard Java.  Please add appropriate tags or provide explanations in the question.

@WJS What are the annotations are not standard Java ?

@K.Nicholas My question is how should I save costElements and Invoice correctly. How can I handle these setter methods correctly ? -> costElement1.setInvoices(); costElements2.setInvoices(); Because even though there is a setter method called -> setInvoices(); But we have only one Invoice. Can anyone please clarify this problem for me ?

@SDeSilva are you using any third party software packages or frameworks?

@WJS Yes, Spring-Boot framework, Lombok ....

@SDeSilva Ah.  I suggest you edit your tags to include the frameworks as they are more important than database  and many-to-many which are just generic.   You can add those later with no more than 5 tags.  That way you will alert those watching for those tags so you can get the proper help.

@SDeSilva Actually, I will do it for you.  Done!  Well, apparently one has no control over the order of the tags.

@SDeSilva - well, if there is only one invoice then it is a one-to-many relationship not a many-to-many. You still haven't explained what your problem is. Never mind this question.
